# Decimal not calculated in my total result

Tags: javascript, decimal, calculator

Why in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CSkLu/23/) the BASE `#subtotal` is not calculated with decimal, if yo try to put a number with decimal in the numbers ( click over the number, its editable), the BASE does not sum the result with decimal

Here the code i have edited

```
$('#subtotal').html(total.toFixed(2));
var vat = parseFloat((0.21 * total).toFixed(2));  
var irpf = parseFloat((0.15 * total).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got a line

```
total += parseInt($(this).text());
```

total is an int... so no decimals.

replace the line by `parseFloat`, or use another var if you need an int result.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSkLu/24/)